Robot class in Javafxml
I am a beginner, and I have a question regarding Robot class in JavaFX. I have the following code.
Basically, when  I manually click on AnchorPane, method click gets activated, and when the mouse enters the AnchorPane, method entered gets fired.
My problem is that when the mouse enters the AnchorPane the output is always:
entered!
You clicked me!

How can I make sure that "entered" prints after Robot class automatically clicks (and therefore "You clicked me!" gets printed first) on AnchorPane?
I really appreciate if you can help me.
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML public AnchorPane canvas;
    
    public void click() {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }

    public void entered() throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        Robot robot1 = new Robot();
        robot1.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot1.delay(10);
        robot1.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        System.out.println("entered!");
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        canvas.setOnMouseClicked( (event) -> {
            click();
        });
        canvas.setOnMouseEntered( (event) -> {
            try {
                entered();
            } catch (AWTException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
    }    
    
}


Why are you using Robot at all here?  JavaFX has a Robot if you need one, but probably you don't need one.  If you do, use the JavaFX Robot, not the AWT Robot.  The code is not really multithreaded, so I am not sure why you have that tag.  JavaFX runs all user code on a single thread.  AWT will use a different thread, but you shouldn't be using it in most cases.

This appears to be an xyproblem.  Please edit the question to explain the context and your objective.

ok so I am a radiologist and I am using a java fx program to facilitate dictation of my cases..very often I switch between apps/programs ( when I scroll through people MRI and CT) and my java fx program wont be the focus anymore...The only way that I thought to solve this issue, was to add code so that when my mouse enters the the program, it automatically does a left click and bring the focus back to my java application...Is there any other way to achieve this? but then I realize when I am using Robot class, code is not performed sequentially (as if it makes a thread and is run parallel)

and really appreciate your advice...But I am not a professional programmer..just do it for fun...I am using Java 1.8 ( very old version..believe it or not that the one on most hospital computer systems)..I dont see JavaFX Robot, I only have the option of AWT Robot.. But again my whole objective is to bring focus back to a java application by bringing the mouse on top of it ..is there a way to do that (with or without Robot class)?

Some window managers allow mouse-scrolling of the content of a window while the mouse hovers over that window—even while a JavaFX application has focus. MacOS is one.

So in hospitals we are using Windows system (not sure if any hospital uses MacOS). but I am using lots of measurements and clicks on images (so definitely lose my Java focus) and then when I bring my mouse on my java application and I want to click a button to add a comment to my report ..but instead that click is wasted on giving the focus to the  java application....even though it does not sound terrible, it is really awful when you do this hundred times a day..so I just want to find a way to give focus to java application when I hoover the mouse on top of it immediately

You could try stage.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET, e -> stage.requestFocus());.  I haven't got a Windows machine to test that, on OS X it doesn't activate the window, but on Windows, it might.  Or maybe try stage.toFront() or stage.setAlwaysOnTop() and see if those improve your usability.  You can set focus follows mouse in the Windows OS, but it seems a bit dodgy from the descriptions in the linked answers.

Thank you. I appreciate it. I have stage.setAlwaysOnTop()  as part of my code. the stage does not get hidden but still lose focus. I have used stage.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET, e -> stage.requestFocus()) and it does not do anything on Mac (I can try to see if it can work on windows, but I think the result would be the same regardless of operating system)

Does this accessibility setting for focus follows mouse on Windows 11 work for you?

@ jewelsea...Thank you so much for this..I was not aware that windows has such a feature..this potentially solve my problem . Btw, I was able to give my application focus using stage.toFront() and it works both on Mac and window..The only issue is that titelbar retains its inactive appearance..Is there a way to change that through Java code?

The only issue is that titelbar retains its inactive appearance..Is there a way to change that through Java code? -> Not directly that I know of.  It could probably done via JNA after getting a native window handle.

If I understand you correctly, you just need a boolean. This example plays the PauseTransitions one after the other. It moves the mouse to the primaryStage. It clicks on the primaryStage. It moves the mouse outside of the primaryStage. Finally, it moves the mouse back into the primaryStage.
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.robot.Robot;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {    
    boolean isMouseClicked = false;
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
     
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        Pane canvas = new Pane();
        canvas.setOnMouseClicked((mouseClickedEvent) -> {
            click();
            if(!isMouseClicked)
            {
                canvas.setOnMouseEntered((mouseEnteredEvent) -> {
                    entered();
                    isMouseClicked = true;
                });
            }
        });
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 400, 600);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        PauseTransition pause0 = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
        pause0.setOnFinished(event ->
        {
           Robot robot = new Robot();
           robot.mouseMove(primaryStage.getX() + 100, primaryStage.getY() + 100);
           robot.mouseClick(MouseButton.PRIMARY);
           System.out.println("Robot auto click 0!");
            
        });
        
        PauseTransition pause1 = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
        pause1.setOnFinished(event ->
        {
           Robot robot = new Robot();
           robot.mouseMove(primaryStage.getX() + 100, primaryStage.getY() -200);
           robot.mouseClick(MouseButton.PRIMARY);
           System.out.println("Robot auto click 1!");           
        });
        
        PauseTransition pause2 = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
        pause2.setOnFinished(event ->
        {
            primaryStage.requestFocus();
            //primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
           Robot robot = new Robot();
           robot.mouseMove(primaryStage.getX() + 100, primaryStage.getY() + 100);
           robot.mouseClick(MouseButton.PRIMARY);
           System.out.println("Robot auto click 2!");
            
        });
        
        SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();
        sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(pause0, pause1, pause2);
        sequentialTransition.play();
        
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void click() 
    {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }
    
    public void entered()
    {
        System.out.println("entered!");    
    }
}

I updated the answer using Robot. Hopefully, this will help.

Recent comments suggest that the user wants a way to scroll content in another application while the JavaFX application remains in the foreground. For example, on MacOS, I hovered over the source code of your program and scrolled though it, while the program ran in the foreground. I defer to your Windows experience.

@trashgod, I was hoping the OP would test the code and give feedback. From what I gathered from the OP's updated comments, the OP might just need to use primaryStage.requestFocus() when the JavaFX needs to regain focus.

On a Mac primaryStage.requestFocus() doesn't grant focus if the stage is not already active (Windows might be different).  You can synthesize a click using the JavaFX Robot, and that will activate the window and give it focus.  It is a bit of a hack to do so, but I don't know another way to accomplish the desired functionality.

@jewelsea, when I added primaryStage.requestFocus(); in pause2.setOnFinished, it looks like it does regain the focus on Windows.

Thank you so much for your help...I actually added :
canvas.setOnMouseEntered( (event) -> {
Stage primaryStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
primaryStage.toFront();
});
and it is gaining focus both on Mac and Windows. There is only one aesthetic issue.  When Java application gains and loses focus, titlebar changes color.  with this code, program gains focus when my mouse hoover on it, but title bar does not change color (retain inactive appearance even though have focus). Is there a way to solve this?

@user11813719, your latest comments should be asked as a new question.
